# "Trivial" Question: Difference between Mass and Measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

What is the difference between mass and measure (in the context of probability theory)? Are they used interchangeably? I couldn't find anything about this and I do not know where to look for it.

Comment: There's no real difference, although 'mass' tends to be used more for discrete measures (e.g., a point mass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to wikipedia:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function the 
probability mass is the number you associate to a discrete set such as a number. 
Example: the probability mass of a coin coming up heads is 0.5

A measure on the other hand is more general and can be used to describe both the probability mass of a discrete set and the probability density of an interval (or more complicated sets, depending on where the measure is defined.)
Example: The  measure of the set $\{heads\}$ is 0.5.